# Get difference from next number divisible by 10

Tags: c#

Hello everyone How can I get the difference between a number and the next number divisible by 10 in c#?

Example.

```
15 should give 5. (20-15 =5)
21 should give 9. (30-21=9)
30 should give 0. (30-30=0)
```

Sorry for my english.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mod won't work, that will give you the opposite of what you want. 21%10=1 not 9 like you want. What you should do is 10-(num%10). This will get you much closer. The only result that will be wrong in this case is 30, which will give a result of 10.

so:

```
(10-(num%10))%10
```

This will give you the correct result everytime, although a bit cumbersome.

Comment: 9 - ((num + 9) % 10) has one % less. Change your answer and let's split the profit :)

Comment: @Dialecticus Except for negative numbers, -22 gives `12` with your simplified formula, `2` with the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

you should use modulus

```
15 % 10 will give 5
21 % 10 will give 1
30 % 10 will give 0
```

Comment: My bad, but this should give him an idea. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the "mod" operator.

```
x=15;
y=x%10; //y=5
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not that stright forward. I dont know exactly the syntax for C#, but here is my approach. You'll need to adapt it to your code

```
    x = 15;
    y = x % 10;
    if y > 0 return 10 - y
    return 0
```